# "is"-reference or gettype()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, comparison

I'm searching inside some `controls` in my WinForms Form, with the help of `foreach` statements.
I'm comparing the object i find through a "is"-reference (`a is DataGridView`). With "a" being an object in a control collecion.
That works fine so far, because the compared objects on my form are all sufficiantly different from one another.

In a new form i created i'm using a derived version of a `DataGridView` called `my_datagridview`. So when a `my_datagridview` is compared to a `DataGridView` through a "is"-reference no exception is thrown, which is "wrong" cause i want to handle the two seperately.

Is there a way to compare `my_datagridview` and `DataGridView` properly?

Comment: Why do you need to loop through controls when you already know which grid should in what way? Just curious.

Comment: @danish: cause it saves me a lot of code. All `DataGridViews` are contained in multiple `GroupBoxes` (2 layers at least) and i have exactly 8 (`DataGridViews`) of them.
It's just more neat this way.

Comment: I still cannot understand the need to find the control. If user action X on screen, should result in action Y in grid Z, why not trap action X and perform action on grid?

Comment: @danish: Because i am not handling an event in a specific `DataGridView`, but an event triggered by some other element, which in return needs the `DataGridViews` to be updated (but not all of them, just specific ones).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to compare my_datagridview and DataGridView properly?

One option would be to use something like:

```
if (a is MyDataGridView) // Type name changed to protect reader sanity
{
}
else if (a is DataGridView)
{
    // This will include any subclass of DataGridView *other than*
    // MyDataGridView
}
```

Or you *could* use `GetType()` to match exactly, of course. The important question is what you would want to happen with any *other* classes derived from `DataGridView` or even from `MyDataGridView`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
I don't have any other derived classes and don't plan on including/creating others.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Start with the most specific class first. So:

```
if (a is my_datagridview)
{
    //....
}
else if (a is DataGridView)
{
    // ....
}
```

[See MDSN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

first I like as better

so

```
var dg = a as DataGrindView
var mygd = a as MyDataGridView

if(mygd != null) {...}
else
{
   if(dg != null) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Upcast always succeeds and downcast always fails!**

**So when you upcast my_datagridview to DataGridView it would always succeed!**

Doing this would cause an **InvalidCastException** as the downcast fails!

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
myDataGrivView m_dgv = (myDataGridView)dgv;
```

To avoid throwing of the above exception,you can use the **as** operator!

Instead of throwing exception it returns null if the downcast fails!

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
myDataGrivView m_dgv =dgv as myDataGridView;

if(m_dgv==null)
{
//its a datagridview
}
else
{
//its a mydatagridview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the more derived version first and perform its actions, then compare the less derived type (assuming that actions are mutually exclusive)

Alternatively, in put the two comparisons in one conditional statement:

```
if ((a is my_datagridview) && (!a is DataGridView))
{
  // This will only match your derived version and not the Framework version
}
// The else is needed if you need to do something else for the framework version.
else if (a is DataGridView)
{
  // This will only match the framework DataGridView because you've already handled
  // your derived version.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on our comments above, I do not see a need to find the controls. For example, if you have a button on the form and by click that something should happen to grid1, you could use this in click event handler for the button:

```
private void ClickButtonOne(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Do something with datagridview here
}
```

Comment: There is no "need" it is just shorter this way.

Comment: Shorter is not always efficient.